# How to adapt frame of half circle to its size

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am making an app where I need to use half circle. But I can't make its frame match the real size of the object. Right now I am trimming the circle but I don't really know you to actually crop the view.

Here is how I trimming the circle:

```
Circle()
   .trim(from: 0, to: 0.5)
   .fill(Color.blue)
   .background(Color.red)
```

And I am getting colour red as background twice bigger the my new object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mask it differently using a `GeometryReader`:

```
GeometryReader { proxy in
    Circle()
        .fill(.blue)
        .offset(y: -proxy.size.height) // <- Shows bottom part
        .frame(height: proxy.size.width) // <- Makes the circle match frame
        .background(.red) // <- Just for testing
}
.aspectRatio(2, contentMode: .fit) // <- Makes the frame ration 2 : 1 (landscape rectangle)
.clipped() // <- Removes out of bound drawings
```

[image: Demo]

Answer (score 4):

It's probably better to make your own `HalfCircle` that conforms to `Shape` instead of trying to bash `Circle` into the shape you need. Let's go the extra mile and make it conform to `InsettableShape`, in case you want to use it to stroke a border.

```
import SwiftUI

struct HalfCircle: InsettableShape {
    var _inset: CGFloat = 0

    func inset(by amount: CGFloat) -> Self {
        var copy = self
        copy._inset += amount
        return copy
    }

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()

        // This is a half-circle centered at the origin with radius 1.
        path.addArc(
            center: .zero,
            radius: 1,
            startAngle: .zero,
            endAngle: .radians(.pi),
            clockwise: false
        )
        path.closeSubpath()

        // Since it's the bottom half of a circle, we only want
        // to inset the left, right, and bottom edges of rect.
        let rect = rect
            .insetBy(dx: _inset, dy: 0.5 * _inset)
            .offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: -(0.5 * _inset))

        // This transforms bounding box of the path to fill rect.
        let transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            .translatedBy(x: rect.origin.x + 0.5 * rect.size.width, y: 0)
            .scaledBy(x: rect.width / 2, y: rect.height)

        return path.applying(transform)
    }
}
```

We can use it to draw this:

[image: the bottom half of a circle]

using this playground:

```
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(HalfCircle()
    .inset(by: 20)
    .fill(.black)
    .background(.gray)
    .aspectRatio(2, contentMode: .fit)
    .frame(width: 200)
    .padding()
)
```